XSL does not appear in XLM Sitemap
Thanks that you exist.
I integrated a sitemap on my website: https://mecker-ecke.com/ and had to create my own because the ASGOROS forum was not indexed on Google or BING. This now works perfectly, even if the XSL is not used.
https://www.loom.com/share/349ee25d39c14c1b9525e712ea9e9254?sid=8549dbce-de03-41e6-8196-cecdf51f2e2b
What am I thinking wrong or what should I do to make it look neat or is it due to the extension of the /asgaros-sitemap/

I use a page template that creates pure XML, and it is written in PHP. The PHP is attached.

I changed the extension of the page to ".xml" but it is lost every time I save it.


The asgaros-sitemap.php Template. https://mecker-ecke.com/wp-content/uploads/support/asgaros-sitemap.php
Thanks for the support

can you try to tell the php to output a content-type header of text/xml?

I try:




but where I have to insert "text/xml"?

did the https:// before mecker-ecke.com in the stylesheet href get swallowed by SO?

Thanks for the reply.
I tried with: "text/xml" and "text/xsl" and with "https://..." and without, but there are no differences.
What surprises me is that even normal formatting doesn't work with "" or "/r/n".
Further suggestions?

Sollte ich das einfügen:
POST /echo/post/xml HTTP/1.1
Host: reqbin.com
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
Content-Length: 118

Wo einfügen meinst du? Mal probiert?

Im Header von der asgaros-sitemap. Etwas anderes fällt mir nicht ein.

OK and thank you. I think that won't work!
